# mysql union, distinct query optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

So I have a simple query as the following:

```
Select DISTINCT A.col1 as col1 
    FROM Table A join Table B on(A.col2 = B.col2)
    JOIN table C on(C.col1 = A.col3)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT A.col1 as col1 
    FROM Table A 
    JOIN Table B on (A.col2 = B. col2) where A.col4 != 'somevalue';
```

as it is visible table A and Table B joins are being performed on the same columns every time. I am unable to figure out a way where I can utilize these details and make this query faster

Comment: Can you explain what the query is doing?  It _might_ suffice to provide the real column/table names.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting joins into `EXISTS` and subquery logic like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.col1 AS col1
FROM TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE B WHERE A.col2 = B.col2
  )
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE C WHERE A.col1 = C.col3
  )
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT A.col1 AS col1
FROM TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE B WHERE A.col2 = B.col2
  )
AND A.col4 != 'somevalue');
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't generally optimize `OR` very well, usually the solution to this is to convert `OR` to `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the comment. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Gurv and Barmar. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Gurv: what if the select statements use a column from each of the joined tables as well? is there a way to optimize such a query ?

Comment: @Paroma Then join is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent, but it does not make a lot of sense:

```
Select DISTINCT A.col1 as col1 
FROM Table A
JOIN Table B  on (A.col2 = B.col2)
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM C WHERE C.col1 = A.col3 )
   OR A.col4 != 'somevalue';
```